# Flex boxes not working fine with Chrome

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox **CSS** to implement some stuff. 
I just want compatibility in **Chrome & Firefox**. 
I am able to do this in FF but doesn't work in **Chrome**. 
What I want is to insert vertical boxes center, recursively. You can have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GuDcM/).

```
div.contenaireBlc {background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ddd;
                      width:250px; height:250px;margin:0 30px 0 0;}


.contenaireHori {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background:#777; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.innerTop{
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 50%;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}


.traversHori{
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 20px;
  background: blue; 
  width: 100%;

}

.innerBottom{
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 50%;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In **chrome**, the second red & green box have **height = 0px**, in place to take left space (50% each).

Comment: Are you elements *really* being used with no content?  http://jsfiddle.net/GuDcM/5/

Comment: In chrome 48 there is a regression bug with `flex-direction:column`. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580196&q=label%3Acr-blink&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified